# Is there a way to move a commit in the git log?

Tags: git

I have a commit I cherry-picked from another branch (not sure if the other branch is relevant), but it appears via the 'git log' that it's adding that commit to the end/top of the history, even though it has the correct date and time for when the commit was made. Is there a way to move this commit back in the log so the date/time makes sense when compared with the other commits?

Comment: Commits have a "commit date" and an "author date". You can do an interactive rebase to edit all commits after a certain point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful what you ask for.  **`git log` lies**, but this is a *good thing!*

OK, "lies" is an overstatement.  But it's worth remembering, `git log` shows you *something*, but it's deliberately a peephole into reality, rather than all of reality at once.  It's a bit like the claim that [time is nature's way of keeping everything from happening at once](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/John_Archibald_Wheeler#Misattributed): `git log` has to show you commits one at a time, but they're *all* there.

#### Commits

First, commits have *two* time stamps, not just one.  By default, `git log` shows you the author date.  The `--since` and `--until` arguments look at the committer date.  For most commits, the two time stamps match, and this doesn't matter.  For cherry-picked commits, or commits made by someone different from the original author, it sometimes *does* matter.  Here's a bit of `git log --pretty=fuller` output showing such a commit:

```
commit 6c6ce21baa9b50d394bb8ed9878944504ffd57d8
Author:     Eric Sunshine <sunshine sunshineco.com>
AuthorDate: Fri Aug 31 04:33:42 2018 -0400
Commit:     Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
CommitDate: Fri Aug 31 12:05:24 2018 -0700

    config.mak.uname: resolve FreeBSD iconv-related compilation warning

    OLD_ICONV has long been needed by FreeBSD so config.mak.uname defines
    it unconditionally. However, recent versions do not need it, and its
    presence results in compilation warnings. Resolve this issue by defining
```

Second—and maybe actually more important—each Git commit stores, as part of its own data, the hash ID of its *parent* commit or commits.  This means that commits have parent/child relationships.  The true name of any Git commit is actually its big ugly hash ID, such as that `6c6ce21...` above.

We can find the parent(s) of a commit using `git rev-parse`, or by looking directly at the commit object:

```
$ git rev-parse 6c6ce21baa9b50d394bb8ed9878944504ffd57d8^1
53f9a3e157dbbc901a02ac2c73346d375e24978c
$ git cat-file -p 6c6ce21baa9b50d394bb8ed9878944504ffd57d8
tree 1832fd8f6315732daca5c0523a951d40a8ee7fb2
parent 53f9a3e157dbbc901a02ac2c73346d375e24978c
author Eric Sunshine ...[snip]
```

The parent/child relationship is defined exclusively through these `parent` lines: all commits are frozen in time, and when you make a commit, it has its parent, but it has no children *yet*.  Since you can't *change* a commit after you make it, the parent cannot remember its children.  But the parent exists so the child can remember its parent.

Let's draw a simple line of commits, giving them one-letter names instead of big ugly hash IDs, where each commit has one parent and one child, except for the very first, or *root* commit—which has no parent—and the last, or *tip* commit, which has no child:

```
A  <-B  <-C  <-D  <-E  <-F  <-G
```

If we start at the end—which Git generally does—we have commit `G` in hand.  So, `git log` marches along, starting with the commit it has in its hand right now and showing commit `G`.  `G` remember's `F`'s big ugly hash ID, so now `git log` marches back one step and shows `F`; then it marches back again to `E`, and to `D`, and so on until it reaches `A`.  We say that each commit *points back* to its parent, and Git follows these pointers.

Git's real trick here is that it somehow finds `G`.  There's nothing in this diagram pointing *to* `G`, so how can Git find it?  The answer is: *branch names*.  We have a branch name like `master`, pointing to commit `G`:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- master
```

Since commits are frozen, and I'm a little lazy, :-) I dropped the internal arrows.  We know they all point backwards, so we don't need them: the lines will do.  The *name* `master` lets Git find commit `G`.  From `G`, Git walks back to `F`, then to `E`, and so on.

The most interesting thing about this is when we go to add a *new* commit.  Let's say we `git checkout master` so that we have commit `G` extracted.  Then, we do some work and run `git add` and `git commit`.  This makes a *new* commit, with a new big ugly hash ID but we'll just call it `H`.  `H` will point back to, i.e., contain the big ugly hash ID of, commit `G`:

```
...--G   <-- master
      \
       H
```

The last thing that Git does is to write `H`'s hash ID into the name `master`, so that `master` now points to `H` (and we can draw the line straight again):

```
...--G--H   <-- master
```

What this means is that *commits never change* (they can't), but *branch names change all the time!*  What Git changes is not the commits, but rather, the *names*.

#### Branching and merging, and how it affects this and `git log`

OK, so we have some nice straight history lines of commits, but now what happens when we make some branches and then merge them?  The answer is that Git makes *merge commits*, which are just commits with *two* parents:

```
          I--J   <-- branch-A
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch-B
```

If we have Git merge the two, we get a new commit `M` that has *both* `J` *and* `L` as its parents:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M
         \    /
          K--L
```

(Exercise: I dropped all the branch names here.  Which branch name(s) does Git update?  How does Git know, when there are two names `branch-A` and `branch-B`, which branch is the one you're working on?  Solving this exercise will teach you a lot about Git.  Or, cheat with the web site I mention below. :-) )

Now, when `git log` is marching along, it will show commit `M`, but then—which commit should it show next, `J`, or `L`?

It needs to show *both* commits.  Ideally, it should show them at the same time, but it *can't*.  It has to pick one to show first.  (Time keeps everything from happening at once.)  This is when—and why—`git log` *has* to lie: it has to show one first, even though `J` and `L` are really "at the same time" just before `M`.

Here, `git log` has a bunch of flags to tell it *how to lie*.  The default lie is to use what you want: the date stamp!  But it's the date stamp that `git log` *doesn't* show you by default, i.e., the committer date, here.  Adding `--author-date-order` makes Git choose the author date instead of the committer date.  Note that this only affects the choice when `git log` has *more than one commit to show right now*—which is true when it's showing, say, `J` instead of `L`.  After it does that, it *still* has two commits to show, namely both `I` and `L`.  It will pick one of these two, using your sorting option, and once again still have two commits to show: `H` and `L`, or `I` and `K`, depending on which one it just showed.

#### This is all too complicated

Well, yes, it is.  Unfortunately, it's the reality.  There is a way to get `git log` to *draw the graph* as well as showing the commits, using `git log --graph`.  That's not always helpful, but when it is helpful, it's *extremely* helpful.

For (much) more about this, see the web site [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  You *need* to know this stuff, eventually anyway, to use Git effectively.  Until then, though, the fact that `git log` lies—that it hides away all this complexity by default—is a good thing.

Comment: Wow, thank you. This is the answer for me -- I was misunderstanding what git was showing me in 'git log', and '--pretty=fuller' showed me what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a rebase and move the commits around but this is not advisable, specially if you have pushed the repo and work with other people because the commit ids will change, breaking all refs.

As commenters point out:

- It's perfectly fine to do if you are working locally, and
- The commit object has actually two dates.

If you care only about the commit ordering "making sense", you can also alter the date of the picked commit using [`rebase --committer-date-is-author-date`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase/2.17.0#git-rebase---committer-date-is-author-date) minimizing potential problems since you probably haven't pushed this specific commit yet.

Comment: I definitely agree in case you already pushed your commits. But if you didn't, then it's perfectly fine to rebase them as you wish.

Comment: This is useful, but in my case, I was misunderstanding what git was showing me, and it's more useful to preserve the history with Author Date.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. But this should be a good thing. Remember that in 'git log' or in the revision history, it describes what the collaborators have done to the repository. What 'git cherry-pick' actually does is not exactly 'copy' a commit, but rather it 'repeats' what you have done from one branch to the current branch you are working on. You can also say that git cherry pick is - "git automated to copy and paste whatever you wrote from that other branch in this commit, and then git committed it in the current branch for you.". Hence, the date is the current date *and it would also not make sense to move the new commit backwards* :).

This is not exactly wrong, because it tells you that some person committed a new code, and that this code was copied from another branch. And it was done today. :)